# Alternate Proofs to this Question?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The question asks:

"Does there exists a non-abelian group of order 2012?"

My answer is yes, an example of which is the dihedral group $D_{1006}$.  I'm curious, though, if anyone can give me a non-constructive proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you could argue as follows : Such a group must have a subgroup $H$ of order 4, and a subgroup $K$ of order 503. There is a non-trivial homomorphism from a group of order 4, to $\mathbb{Z}_{503}^{\times} \cong Aut(K)$, and this will give a non-abelian semi-direct product.

Comment: I would call that non-constructive! I am not convinced that "constructive" makes much sense in a situation where there are only finitely many possibilties.